# How to filter the sub-lists in webix

Tags: list, combobox, hide, show

Here our requirement is, if we search vf(value field) values in combo, means only searching value should be shown in combo list remaining should be hide.

for example in synonyms 3 values are present['hr','hrs','hour'], if we search hr means, only hr value should be shown, remaining two values should be hide??

plz follow bellow snippet
https://webix.com/snippet/ff18c9ea

thank's in advance
Deepak